# MultiFormatReader unable to read the qr although the qr is scannable

Tags: java, android, image-processing, qr-code, zxing

The qr image i have attached is scannable (using ZXingScannerView (a github lib https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner for android) or some other QR Code scanning application) but MultiFormatReader is giving NotFoundException when i pick this image from the storage to scan it. I simply want to scan the qr Code from the storage. and that QR code image would have almost equivalent quality to the image i have attached

[this is the qr code i want to scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVNLU.png)
i tried the below code it is giving NotFoundException.

```
public static String scanQRImage(Bitmap bMap) {
String contents = null;

 if (bMap.getHeight() > 500 && bMap.getWidth() > 500)
     bMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, bMap.getWidth() - 300, bMap.getHeight() - 300, false);

 int[] intArray = new int[bMap.getWidth() * bMap.getHeight()];

 //copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array
 bMap.getPixels(intArray, 0, bMap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight());

 LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), intArray);
 BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

 Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
 Map<DecodeHintType, Object> tmpHintsMap = new EnumMap<>(
         DecodeHintType.class);
 tmpHintsMap.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
 tmpHintsMap.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS,
         EnumSet.allOf(BarcodeFormat.class));
 tmpHintsMap.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.TRUE);
 try {
     Result result = reader.decode(bitmap, tmpHintsMap);
     contents = result.getText();
 } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e("QrTest", "Error decoding barcode", e);
 }
 return contents;
}
```

once again in simple words. i want to scan a bit distorted qr code image present in the storage.
Please Help